# Can you satisfy an interface with an IEnumerable<T> by using List<T>?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let's say I have the following Model:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    IEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class Product : IProduct
{
    public IEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
}
```

But I want `Ingredients` to be a `List<Ingredient>` instead of an `IEnumerable<Ingredient>`

Is there a way to model the interface to accept `IEnumerable<T>` and `List<T>`?

I tried the following.  But of course, the syntax doesn't support this and doesn't see `TEnumerable<Ingredient>` as a generic parameter.

```
public interface IProduct<TEnumerable<Ingredient>> 
    where TEnumerable<Ingredient> : IEnumerable<Ingredient>
{
    TEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class Product : IProduct
{
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
}
```

I realize this isn't very practical, but I am just looking at this with curiosity in mind.

Comment: Remember the LSP. The reason you can't do this "directly" is that you couldn't say, call `new Product().Ingredients = Enumerable.Empty<Ingredient>()`. I.e. the subclass would violate its interface that says `(new Product() as IProduct).Ingredients = Enumerable.Empty<Ingredient>()` should be valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off:

- You can't declare a type parameter in a generic way like this
- Your `Product` type needs to specify a type argument when it says how it's implementing `IProduct<TEnumerable>`

So this is valid:

```
public interface IProduct<TEnumerable> 
    where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<Ingredient>
{
    TEnumerable Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class Product : IProduct<List<Ingredient>>
{
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

It may not be *helpful*, but at least it's valid...

Comment: It might be worth mentioning you can't actually assign an instance of `Product` to a variable of `IProduct<IEnumerable<Ingredient>>`, which makes this construct somewhat less useful than it seems.

Comment: Hah! I see where I went wrong.  Thanks Jon, and as always, you're amazingly quick.  I didn't expect to see anything for a few more minutes yet.

Comment: @millimoose I already see this as completely useless, just playing with syntax :)

Comment: @Khan Fair enough, I was just trying to head off probably the single most asked question about generics, period. (The "Why can't I assign `Foo<Y>` to a variable of type `Foo<X>` if `Y` extends `X`?" one.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you interested in having your concrete implementation of `IProduct` use `List<>` internally, or interested in exposing `List<>` in some implementations and `IEnumerable` in another?

If it's the former, you don't need to do anything - `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so if `Product` has an internal `List<Ingredient>`, you can simply return it as `IEnumerable<Ingredient>`:

```
public class Product : IProduct
{
   private List<Ingredient> _ingredients;
   public IEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients { get { return _ingredients; } }
}
```

If, however, you're interested in the second option (which Jon Skeet's answer fixes for you), I'll have to ask you why you'd want that, since it mainly makes the interface more difficult to consume - instead of having a uniform contract that all callers adhere to, you have an generic meta-interface that is used differently by different callers. It's an interesting concept, but seems like overkill if all you want to do is replace IEnumerable with IList.